# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704 in connecting to db2

Tags: docker, db2

I'm running db2 database in docker. 
I created a  'test 'database.

```
db2 create db test
db2 connect to test user <username> using <password>
```

And when trying to connect to that database through flowing configurations by adding db2jcc4 jar file .

```
type = "db2"
url = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/AMDB"
username = <username>
password = <password>
```

Iam getting this error

```
 ERROR - DatabaseUtil Database Error - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2INST1.UM_DIALECT, DRIVER=3.72.44 . com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2INST1.UM_DIALECT, DRIVER=3.72.44
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL0204N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0204n) means, that the object is not defined in the database.
Your client tool probably uses this `UM_DIALECT` user table or view (it’s not a system object), but it doesn’t exist in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting up the WSO2 Identity Server, then you will need to create its metadata tables before you start any of the WSO2 Identity-server tools.

For Db2, these steps are documented [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+IBM+DB2).